# Retrieving the Omniture tracking call url before calling s.t()

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I'd like to use an old *s_code.js* to generate a url that I can use to track an event, but I'd like not to use `s.t()` as it provides no way of keeping tabs on the request. Is there any way to get the url as a *String* before sending off the tracking request with `s.t()`?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you looking to evaluate the URL of a link click before you call s.t()? Do you need to set an event if a certain URL is found and then make the tracking call?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the url of the tracking call will be, before calling s.t(). s.t uses the window's s object to construct a url and then ping it, effectively making the tracking call. I need that url without actually pinging it.

Comment: but...why? I feel like there's probably a simpler answer for what you are actually wanting. Are you trying to keep track of previous AA variables sent?

Comment: I need to send the tracking requests separately from their initial load and monitor them from a system far up and away from the webview that is running the page to be tracked. In general omniture's methods of monitoring the request and reporting success or failure is completely inadequate.

Comment: So it sounds like what you *really* want is to get the http response code from the request.. that's not really possible except for with AJAX calls made to your own domain, or AJAX calls to somewhere that allows cross-domain scripting - something that basically nobody allows.  Adobe Analytics (Omniture) has a lot of different ways to send data to their servers, not just javascript.  You can send the data back to your own server and then make the requests at your leisure and things like http headers are exposed.  This will only really work if you have a first party tracking implementation though

Comment: Yes - that's exactly the intention. I will not be sending the request using javascript. Javascript and the browser/webview are used solely to (hopefully) obtain the url to ping - not for conducting the actual request or to monitor the status. That being said, the point is to obtain the url that the request *would* be sent to - without actually sending the request :)

Comment: Well then seems to me the easiest solution is to just pop `s.trackingServer` as your own domain/script and go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to pull from a mixture of methods in order to get this data. There is no one method (at least in AppMeasurement) that will get this for you. A combination of `s.pb` (builds the domain and path, but also calls for the creation of the request), `s.gb` for the build of URL parameters, and `s.t` for the build of the cache buster. YMMV given this is in the core library with 0 expectations of internal methods not getting renamed.

I guess my question is why you're wanting to do this. There are options of preventing the call from being made, but needing to inspect the URL is a first for me.

Comment: Thank you :) I've answered a similar question in the comments to my original question.

Comment: @schellsan that is not going to work.  Firstly unless you have fpc tracking, that is cross site scripting which is not allowed.  But even if you have fpc tracking, AA requests are made by creating an image object.

Comment: Good point. In that case I can replace document.createElement. Much appreciated.